# WGET: want all files/pdfs from a site, dir gets created, but no files are downloaded

Tags: download, wget

I'm apparently too oblivious to (w)get all teh slides.

Having a pdf & ppt filled site: http://some.uni.edu/~name/slides.html
I'd like to download all the (many) linked files in one go.
So far the dir gets made by wget, but it's empty.

I tried:

```
wget -r -A.pdf,.ppt http://some.uni.edu/~name/slides.html
wget -e robots=off -A.pdf,.ppt -r -l1 http://some.uni.edu/~name/slides.html
wget -nd -l -r -e robots=off http://some.uni.edu/~name/slides.html 
wget -r -np -R "slides.html" http://some.uni.edu/~name/slides.html  
wget -r -np -R "slides.html" http://some.uni.edu/~name/
```

So for example:

```
$ wget -r https://web.cs.ucla.edu/~kaoru/
--2018-10-29 21:38:50--  https://web.cs.ucla.edu/~kaoru/
Resolving web.cs.ucla.edu (web.cs.ucla.edu)... 131.179.128.29
Connecting to web.cs.ucla.edu     (web.cs.ucla.edu)|131.179.128.29|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 623 [text/html]
Saving to: ‘web.cs.ucla.edu/~kaoru/index.html’

web.cs.ucla.edu/~ka 100%[===================>]     623  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2018-10-29 21:38:51 (19.1 MB/s) -     ‘web.cs.ucla.edu/~kaoru/index.html’ saved [623/623]

Loading robots.txt; please ignore errors.
--2018-10-29 21:38:51--  https://web.cs.ucla.edu/robots.txt
Reusing existing connection to web.cs.ucla.edu:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 95 [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘web.cs.ucla.edu/robots.txt’

web.cs.ucla.edu/rob 100%[===================>]      95  --.-KB/s        in 0s      

2018-10-29 21:38:51 (3.10 MB/s) - ‘web.cs.ucla.edu/robots.txt’ saved [95/95]

--2018-10-29 21:38:51--  https://web.cs.ucla.edu/~kaoru/paper11.gif
Reusing existing connection to web.cs.ucla.edu:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 10230 (10.0K) [image/gif]
Saving to: ‘web.cs.ucla.edu/~kaoru/paper11.gif’

web.cs.ucla.edu/~ka 100%[===================>]   9.99K  --.-KB/s    in 0.001s  

2018-10-29 21:38:51 (12.3 MB/s) -     ‘web.cs.ucla.edu/~kaoru/paper11.gif’ saved [10230/10230]

FINISHED --2018-10-29 21:38:51--
Total wall clock time: 0.9s
Downloaded: 3 files, 11K in 0.001s (12.2 MB/s)
```

Still downloads no files:

```
$ ls 
$ index.html  paper11.gif
```

Comment: Did you try `--ignore-case`?  Otherwise `-A.pdf` does not match `.PDF`.

Comment: Thanks! Just tried it, no success..

Comment: Are the target PDFs on the same server?  Try `-H` to allow wget to visit other hosts.  Obviously it's hard to answer without access to the page in question.

Comment: I understand, yes, all the files are located at "http://some.uni.edu/~name/" so for example, "http://some.uni.edu/~name/slides001.pdf", "http://some.uni.edu/~name/slides002.ppt" etc.

Comment: Ok, that *should* work.  It's unlikely, but the server could be blocking based on user-agent (etc.).  Can you `wget` one of those direct file URLs?  e.g.: `wget  https://some.uni.edu/~name/slides002.ppt`

Comment: Yes, that works. Not sure what the issue is..

Comment: I think you have completely misunderstood the functionality of `wget`. It won't download links found inside a html file!! I can only recursively download files from a *folder*

Comment: That is possible :) But what is thenh the best way to achieve what I'm trying?

Comment: What do you mean "still download no files"? It downloaded two files, index.html and paper 11.gif. How are you so sure there are more files in that directory?

Comment: I want all the files from here `https://web.cs.ucla.edu/~kaoru/ppt.html` but I can't specify this url, as you mention. So I'm a bit lost.

Answer (score 1):

Your examples

```
wget -r -A.pdf,.ppt http://some.uni.edu/~name/slides.html
wget -e robots=off -A.pdf,.ppt -r -l1 http://some.uni.edu/~name/slides.html
wget -nd -l -r -e robots=off http://some.uni.edu/~name/slides.html 
wget -r -np -R "slides.html" http://some.uni.edu/~name/slides.html
```

should not work the way you want, since you are specifically targeting a single `html`-file, namely `slides.html`. You should be targeting the directory.

However, your last example is the closest I think.

Since @Kingsley 's example works for you, you should try this first, and then starting to `-R` and `-A` files.

```
wget -r http://some.uni.edu/~name/
```

Maybe it should be `https`!?

Anyway, if "directory listing" is not permitted (controlled by server), then `wget` can not get all files recursively. It can only get specific files which you know the names of!

Comment: Thanks! 
Actually, the example works partially - I can get ONE file from the direct URL.I still had to manually get all the PDF's..

Comment: @marc111011 which file is downloaded from the example?

Comment: When I use `wget https://some.uni.edu/~name/slides002.ppt` I do indeed get `slides002.ppt`. But I'd then have to do this 50 times, and clicking is faster than changing names :)

Comment: @marc111011 Then I have two questions. 1. Do you use `http` or `https` ? 2. What do you get when using `wget -r https://some.uni.edu/~name/`

Comment: Thanks - I edited my question for some additional details.

Comment: Appologies - I accidentally edited your answer instead of my question! Please discard it!

Comment: @marc111011  You still havent shown the output of `wget -r https://some.uni.edu/~name/`. Instead in your example you have, again targeted a specific file, namely `ppt.html`. You should target a directory. I.e you last input in the url should end with a `/`, not a specific filename

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but without success. I'm probably missing some relevant point :/

Answer (score 0):

```
wget -h |grep np,
```

-np, --no-parent                 don't ascend to the parent directory

```
wget -h |grep A,
```

-A,  --accept=LIST               comma-separated list of accepted extensions

```
wget -h |grep r,
```

-r,  --recursive                 specify recursive download

Try to use

```
wget -r -np -A pdf,doc https://web.cs.ucla.edu/~harryxu/
```

Result

```
tree

└── web.cs.ucla.edu
    ├── ~harryxu
    │   ├── papers
    │   │   ├── chianina-pldi21.pdf
    │   │   ├── dorylus-osdi21.pdf
    │   │   ├── genc-pldi20.pdf
    │   │   ├── jaaru-asplos21.pdf
    │   │   ├── jportal-pldi21.pdf
    │   │   ├── li-sigcomm20.pdf
    │   │   ├── trimananda-fse20.pdf
    │   │   ├── vigilia-sec18.pdf
    │   │   ├── vora-asplos17.pdf
    │   │   ├── wang-asplos17.pdf
    │   │   ├── wang-osdi18.pdf
    │   │   ├── wang-osdi20.pdf
    │   │   ├── wang-pldi19.pdf
    │   │   └── zuo-eurosys19.pdf
```

Comment: This looks like a succinct and useful answer to the question! You could improve it by elaborating on the CLI arguments that you used and why this works and why the steps described in the question didn't.